Hydrostatic pressure on the side wall
I understand well that pressure from the liquid acts perpendicularly on the walls of a cylindrical container. This applies to liquids and gases.
I am trying to re-understand sth from the university times from soil mechanics... Basically, let's say that instead of water I have a tiny salt crystals. Can I model the pressure on the sides in the same way? Do I need to take into account the cohesion between salt crystals?
Taking cohesion into account works only for soils?

A pile of salt crystals can be modeled in various ways. If we choose to model it as an ideal fluid, then the hydrostatic equation applies to the lateral pressure. If we choose to model it as a jammed granular material, then the lateral pressure could be different. What problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

I don't know what I am trying to solve ultimately. Thanks. That solves my issue :)
